# How do you turn a php tag into a hper link

Tags: php, meta

I have created a wordpress meta field .

I can output that to the front end using :

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($id, "projecturl", true); ?>
```

What I am not sure of is how to turn the custom field value e.g http://myproject.com into a hyperlink.

At the moment the front end is displaying the text http://myproject.com when I want it to say " view project" which is then a clickable link to what ever the field value is.

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards

Ricky

Comment: You need to learn HTML.

Comment: I was following some instructions from woo themes. Thanks again for your feedback, I appreciate I have a long way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is insanely simple, why move to `PHP` before learning `HTML`

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($id, "projecturl", true); ?>">view project</a>
```

Comment: Hi HP, thank you. I am slowing learning php and find that good experts like yourself can answer specific questions / scenarios that actually helps me learn faster. Thanks again or your help :)